# Comparing double values using stream filter

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I need your help in determining what is wrong with the code that I am working on right now.

The specifications for this task is to filter the list of objects obtained from a csv file and only get the top 10 employees with the highest salary. I am trying these lines:

```
List<Employee> listOfTop10HighestPaidMaleEmployee = new ArrayList<>(employeeList);
    List<Employee> filterSalary;

            filterSalary = listOfTop10HighestPaidMaleEmployee
                    .stream()
                    .sorted(
                            Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary)
                    )
                    .limit(10)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When I test it using a for-each loop, it prints out 10 values, but doesn't properly filter out the salary part. I get this output:

```
Employee{id='261461', name='Lucila Isai Gray Silvestre', department='Software Development Team', 
gender=M, age=34, employment status=Permanent, salary=20079.75, years of service=9}
Employee{id='368487', name='Joey Quinn Uson Solivio', department='Marketing', gender=M, age=34, 
employment status=Not Permanent, salary=20200.25, years of service=3}
Employee{id='353810', name='Carter Jamie Pagsisihan Lingao', department='Marketing', gender=M, 
age=24, employment status=Permanent, salary=20444.25, years of service=4}
Employee{id='330680', name='Erick Colby Magan Formalouza', department='IT Services', gender=M, 
age=52, employment status=Permanent, salary=20887.0, years of service=14}
Employee{id='220888', name='Jack Cornelius Parker Guinto', department='IT Services', gender=M, 
age=32, employment status=Permanent, salary=20950.0, years of service=10}
Employee{id='215350', name='Eugenio Jermaine Quiblat Bonachita', department='Marketing', gender=M, 
age=45, employment status=Not Permanent, salary=21263.5, years of service=2}
Employee{id='257430', name='Malaya Kaitlyn Hakamada Gonz�lez', department='IT Services', gender=F, 
age=35, employment status=Not Permanent, salary=21362.0, years of service=2}
Employee{id='212292', name='Kendra Mercedes Lomondot Fernando', department='Marketing', gender=F, a 
age=41, employment status=Not Permanent, salary=21371.75, years of service=3}
Employee{id='348771', name='Kristofer Israel Dura Portugal', department='Human Resource', gender=M, 
age=49, employment status=Permanent, salary=21402.5, years of service=6}
Employee{id='353227', name='Maegan Jaden Mahiya Isidro', department='Human Resource', gender=F, 
age=59, employment status=Not Permanent, salary=21442.25, years of service=3}
```

Upon cross-checking the results and the list, it prints out the list with salary of range 20000-21,000. In the original list, the salary goes up to 30,000. Any tips on how can I filter the list so that it shows the list of 10 employees with the highest salary? Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary)` would sort ascending. You need to reverse that: `Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary).reversed()` or something like that.

Comment: @ernest_k Thank you! Finally found the result that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Added the .reversed() line,

```
listOfTop10HighestPaidMaleEmployee = listOfTop10HighestPaidMaleEmployee
                        .stream() 
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary).reversed())
                        .limit(10)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This gets the last 10 of the list sorted in descending order.

Here is a complete example. Uses the new Java 16 [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature for brevity.

```java
record Employee(String name , double salary) {}

List < Employee > employees =
        List.of(
                new Employee( "Alice" , 88 ) ,    // # 1
                new Employee( "Bob" , 52 ) ,      // # 3
                new Employee( "Carol" , 33 ) ,
                new Employee( "Dennis" , 22 ) ,
                new Employee( "Ellen" , 77 ) ,    // # 2
                new Employee( "Francis" , 17 )
        );

List < Employee > highestPaid =
        employees
                .stream()
                .sorted(
                        Comparator.comparingDouble( Employee :: salary ).reversed()
                )
                .limit( 3 )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );  // Or just `.toList()` in Java 16+.

System.out.println( "highestPaid = " + highestPaid );
```

When run.

> highestPaid = [Employee[name=Alice, salary=88.0], Employee[name=Ellen, salary=77.0], Employee[name=Bob, salary=52.0]]

Comment: @BasilBourque Oh, thank you for that. Yes, it is correct.